# Rails: Creating new Ruby on Rails app in existing directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I've been away from Ruby on Rails development for some time, going through several system updates. This occurred on Mac OS X Sierra, with its system version of Ruby (2.0.0p648), and Rails 4.0.2.

Creating a new app (`rails new appname`) works fine when the `appname` directory doesn't exist---the command creates the app and populates it as it should. However, despite what all the guidebooks and tutorials say, it fails when such a directory exists (even when it's empty). You also can't create an empty directory, cd into it, and run `rails new .`

The output of the failed command looks like this:

> exist
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:97:in
> `create_root': uninitialized constant Rails::Generators::AppBase::FileUtils (NameError)     from (eval):1:in` create_root'     from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
> `run'     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in` invoke_command'  from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in
> `block in invoke_all'     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in` each'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in
> `map'     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in` invoke_all'  from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in
> `dispatch'    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in` start'   from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:43:in
> `<top (required)>'    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in` require'     from
> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in
> `require'     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in` <top (required)>'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in
> `require'     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in` require'     from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'  from /usr/bin/rails:22:in` load'    from
> /usr/bin/rails:22:in `'

How do I get rails to be able to create the app in an existing directory?

Answer (score 12):

For me, I just needed a way of creating a **Rails** app inside an existing directory.

The directory already had a `.git` folder inside it, and I also wanted to use the same git repository which the current app was using for the rails app.

**Here's how I did it**:

All I had to do was to cd into the folder where the app resides:

```
cd myapp
```

And then create the rails app inside the folder, skipping `git` in the process to avoid git conflict and specifying `postgresql` as my database:

```
rails new . --database=postgresql --skip-git
```

**Note**: The existing project didn't have a `.gitignore` file, so since my rails new command skipped `git`, I had to manually create the `.gitignore` file.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Hi, I tried this now and got an error saying, "Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another..." 
I just want to cleanly add postgresql and skip test

Answer (score 9):

After fruitless online searches for the same problem, I went straight to the reported source: Line 97 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb. That line looks like this:

`FileUtils.cd(destination_root) unless options[:pretend]`

According to the error message, it can't find `FileUtils`, treating it as an uninitialized constant. This line is also the only place in the app_base.rb file that uses `FileUtils`.

I went to the top of the file and added `require 'fileutils'` to its requirements. I saved it (this required the admin password), and `rails new .` worked perfectly.

While this fixes the immediate problem, I still have questions. Was this always there, and I haven't noticed, or did it appear after an upgrade as I surmised (most likely from Ruby 1.8 or 1.9 to Ruby 2.0). What changed to cause it?

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the exact same issue today, nearly a year later. Did you ever file an issue with the Rails team? I wonder if this has been fixed in Rails 5?